# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sun.net.www.protocol.http.NTLMAuthSequence.initFirst()V

Tags: java, security, ntlm, jaas

```
package sun.net.www.protocol.http;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Test
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      System.out.println(new NTLMAuthSequence(null, null, null));
   }
}
```

Any idea on why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classloader was the issue. So solution for me was to create a jar file containing above class file and put into the jre bin folder so that it can be read by the same classloader.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a native library that provides the `initFirst()` method.

The sources I found online say this: `private native static void initFirst ();`

If this method should be part of the JRE, your installation might be corrupt or you might have an older version.

Comment: I have confirmed that this method is a part of JRE. and I am using JRE 1.6

Comment: Could you give more information on which JRE/JDK you're using and your OS? It seems like either a native library is missing, just not linked or does not provide the required method.

Comment: Windows 7
java version "1.6.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

Native Library Name: %JAVA_HOME%\bin\net.dll

I have also checked out that this dll is successfully loaded.

Comment: @Thomas - Would you mind running the same program on your machine and post the results? I have even tried on WindowsXP with same error.

Comment: Could you try a 32-bit JRE? I'm not sure here but there but in the past the 64-bit JREs had problems with native code server times.

Comment: Just a side note: You're directly accessing JRE internal classes, which isn't a good idea in almost any case.

Comment: FYI - This purpose of this code to read the windows NTLM credential from LSA. This class is in-directly called from java.net.URLConnection class to authentication user against NTLM based challenge received from server and it works good with 64 bit JRE.

Comment: Yes, I tried with a 1.5 JRE and get the same. That method seems to be missing in the standard setup.

Comment: java.net.URLConnection class also uses this method and it works fine so i don't think that it's standard setup issue.

Comment: Okay so I figured out the problem and It was Classloader issue. So solution for me was to create a jar file with above class file and put into the jre bin folder so that it can be read by the same classloader.